# Remove elements from two lists based on another list

Tags: c#, list, removeall

I have three lists. `List1` contains some strings. `List2` contains some numbers (uint in my case, although that's not very important) and it always has the exact same number of elements as the first one. `List3` always has less elements and it also has some strings. Take notice that `List1` contains all the elements that `List3` has (as well as more strings).

What I want to do is to remove all elements from `List1` that are included in `List3`. However, I also want to remove elements from `List2` in this way: If (for example), the 5th element of `List1` has to be removed, then the 5th element from `List2` has to removed. If the 12th element of `List1` has to removed, then the 12th element from `List2` has to be removed and so on.

I can remove the elements from `List1` with this code: `List1.RemoveAll(x => List3.Contains(x))`.
However, I'm not very familiar with the `RemoveAll` method and I'm not sure how to remove the elements that I want from `List2` in the way that I described.

Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at perhaps `List1.Except()` function

Comment: Loop through list3 check if list1 contains it. Then get the index and remove it from list 1 and 2 with the index number.

Comment: Sounds like an array-based algorithm is better suited to your needs. You want a linear operation, not quadratic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop backward over the list, because then you can remove the elements from the end of the list, example:

```
for (var i = list1.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (list3.Contains(list1[i]))
    {
        list1.RemoveAt(i);
        list2.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple that I was wondering why I didn't come up with this idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested,  a simple loop and index finder:

```
 list3.ForEach(x =>
   {  
      var index = list1.FindIndex(list3.Contains);
      list2.RemoveAt(index);
      list1.RemoveAt(index);
   }
```

But if first list contains duplicates:

```
 var query = list1.Where(list3.Contains).Select((value, index) => new {index}).ToList();
     query.ForEach(x =>
        {
           list2.RemoveAt(x.index);
           list1.RemoveAt(x.index);
        });
```

Comment: `FindIndex` returns only the index of the first match. If there are duplicates it will miss them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `List1` and `List2` could be combined into a `Dictionary<string, int>` if they are meant to be related? Then removing the data from `List1` and `List2` would amount to just deleting a `KeyValuePair`. But of course, `List1` must not have any duplicates, otherwise the dictionary will have duplicate keys.

If a `Dictionary` would make sense semantically (with `List1` containing the keys and `List2` containing the corresponding values), here's an implementation:

```
Dictionary<string, uint> dictionary = List1.ToDictionary(key => key, key => List2[List1.IndexOf(key)];
Dictionary<string, uint> result = dictionary.Where(keyValuePair => !List3.Contains(keyValuePair.Key));
```

A similar implementation can be used if `List2` should contain the keys and `List1` should contain the values:

```
Dictionary<uint, string> dictionary = List2.ToDictionary(key => key, key => List1[List2.IndexOf(key)];
Dictionary<uint, string> result = dictionary.Where(keyValuePair => !List3.Contains(keyValuePair.Value));
```

Having `List1` and `List2` be so strongly connected (both lists have same number of elements; if an element is deleted from `List1`, then the corresponding element should be deleted from `List2`) suggests that a `Dictionary` may be appropriate. (But it's just a suggestion. If a `Dictionary` doesn't work, I would use Dzienny's simple and effective loop-based solution.)

Comment: I actually ended up using Dzienny's solution. However, I really like this idea, so I'll keep this somewhere. It might come handy later. Thank you for your time!